# How to i18n a Spring RestController on java.validation constraints?

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, spring-web, javax.validation

How can I i18n a spring `@RestController` property on `javax.validation` constraints?

I thought I could just add `/src/main/resources/messages.properties` and `messages_de.properties`, and then `spring` would detect them and enable proper i18n? But that seems not to be the case:

```
@RestController
public void TestController {
       @PostMapping
       public void post(@Valid @RequestBody Person p) {
       }
}

public class Person {
       private String firstname;

       @javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank(message = "{errors.person.lastname}")
       private String lastname;
}

messages.properties:
errors.person.lastname=person should provide a lastname

messages_de.properties:
errors.person.lastname=Person ohne Nachnamen
```

Problem: if I now send a `POST` request:

```
{
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException",
    "message": "'lastname': {errors.person.lastname}"
}
```

**Question 1**: do I really have to tell spring explicit to apply i18n as follows? Or can I somehow rely on auto-detect features?

Next step was adding the following configuration. Now the default message is resolved properly. But is it necessary to really add this whenever I want to have validation i18n?

```
@Configuration
public class MessageSourceConfig {
    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource bundle = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        bundle.setBasenames("messages");
        return bundle;
    }
}
```

**Question 2**: I those beans are required: how can I now send a post request to switch the language?
I tried adding get-query parameters like `?local=de, locale=de, ?lang=de, language=de`, but none of them worked...

Comment: Spring Boot autoconfigures the `MessageSource` it doesn't however integrate automatically with the `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`. For changing the locale you need to configure a `LocaleResolver` which allows this (default configured is the `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` which doens't allow changing the `Locale`. And you need to properly configure the `LocaleChangeInterceptor`.

Comment: Ok I see, so having a http header `Accept-Language=de` would be fine too. But why do I still need the `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` and `MessageSource` then? Can't spring autodetect my bundles for `javax.validation`?

Comment: The bundles are the default Spring `MessageSource` bundles, Spring Boot already autoconfigures the `MessageSource` BUT (as stated earlier) doesn't bind that to the `LocalValidatorFactory`.

Comment: One more question: can I tell spring to initialize the default `MessageSource` with `fallbackToSystemLocale=false`? Or would I then have to create my own `@Bean` configuration overriding the default message source?

Comment: I suggest a read of the Spring Boot Reference g uide. Especially the [appendix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html), hint look for `spring.messages`.

Answer (score 5):

With the help of @M. Deinum above, this is the missing peace:

```
    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean(MessageSource messageSource) {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
        return bean;
    }
```

Then having to send a web request with http header `Accept-Language=de`.